# Admob Interstitial on cocos2dx 2.2.3

Tags: java, android, c++, admob, cocos2d-x

im writing a cross platform app in C++ and right now i want to implement admob. Im not sure how to do it, right now im trying to use JNI. However when calling interstitial.isLoaded(), my application 
crash without errors. Any solution will be appreciated

**EDIT SOLVED SOLUTION BELOW**

Under .cpp

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
JniMethodInfo t;

if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t,
    "com.example.mygame/mygame",
    "loadAdmob",
    "()V"))
{

    t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID);
    t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
}
#endif
```

Under Cocos2dxActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    // Create the interstitial.
    final String ADMOB_ID = "my-id";
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_ID);

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("device-id").build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

    appActivity = this;
}

public static void loadAdmob() {
    appActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```